# Keep rows only with constant size of collectList using rowsBetween window function in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I applied the window function to fetch 10 rows and have a collect list run on it as follows:

```
featureWindowSpec = Window.partitionBy("x").orderBy(asc("x"), asc("y")).rowsBetween(0, 9)
list_z = collect_list(col("z")).over(featureWindowSpec)
```

Using this function, I get rows with `list_z` having 10 values but for the last few rows they start reducing to 9, 8, 7 etc because there are no rows further. I want to ignore such rows (the ones having lesser number of `list_z` values). What is the most efficient way to do so? Right now I could only think of filtering using `size` function after creating the `list_z` function (was wondering if we could do it while creating the window itself).

Comment: i don't think there's an easier approach other than the filter of array size.